# Jenkins Pipeline - How to upload folder to S3?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have, as I think, simple use case, when jenkins builds static website, so in the end of the build, I have a folder like $WORKSPACE/site-result.

Now I want to upload this folder to S3 (and clean bucket if something already there). How can I do it?

I'm using pipeline, but can switch to freestyle project if necessary. So far I installed S3 Plugin (S3 publisher plugin). Created IAM user. Added credentials to "Configure system" section. And can't find any further info. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the answer suggesting the Pipeline AWS Plugin doesn't work, you could always have an `upload` step in your pipeline where you use `sh` call the AWS CLI:

`aws s3 cp $WORKSPACE/site-result s3://your/bucket --recursive --include "*"`

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: Hi I have a similar use case,

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **s3Upload** plugin and set the **sourceFile** parameter as '*/*'