# Files will not move or copy from folder on file system to local bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using the command

```
aws s3 mv --recursive Folder s3://bucket/dsFiles/
```

The aws console is not giving me any feedback. I change the permissions of the directory

```
sudo chmod -R 666 ds000007_R2.0.1/
```

It looks like AWS is passing through those files and giving "File does not exist" for every directory.

I am confused about why AWS is not actually performing the copy is there some size limitation or recursion depth limitation?

Comment: You are saying `s3://s3Folder/...` and I assume it's not an indication of an oversight on your part, but to be cleae, this is actually `s3://bucket-name/...`.

Comment: Yes of course. S3://bucket/folder. I can copy files but not large folders. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to `cp`, not `mv`. Try the following:

`aws s3 cp $local/folder s3://your/bucket --recursive --include "*"`.

Source, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744366/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-upload-folder-to-s3/42774976#42774976).

Comment: I believe I have tried that as well. I will give that a shot tonight and get back to you. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I swore I used the cp command. I am at a loss why it is working now. aws s3 cp folder/ s3://bucket/folder --recursive --include "*"

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :)